# Prestashop installation fails at Modules step

Tags: ftp, installation, prestashop, filezilla

I am trying to install latest version of Prestashop and it fails when installing modules.

I get no error description, just that modules could not be installed and that I can try again.

Comment: I had this problem. This fixed it for me -> https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/00addeef5766979b62ef9ab5cd6104a111ef64e7

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question because maybe some day someone finds this useful.

I did some debugging to see where did the installation fail, and it was giving an error complaining about calling the install() method ona  non-object variable.

I changed some php code in the modules install script, and I saw it was failing in the statnewsletter module.

I did not knew why was that, so what I did is go to the FTP and check the files of that module, and surprise, all files had 0 bytes size!

So, the porblem was that my FTP client (Filezilla) did not upload the files correctly.

I've uploaded all the prestashop files again overriding all files and then the installation worked fine.

What I've found on the web is that Filezilla can leave the file with 0 size if the server doesn't respond on the 20seconds timeout limit. And that the timeout limit can be increased in Options to avoid this happening.

Hope helps someone!